# Why does the angularJS two-way binding stop working when I add jasmine-all?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JulianMayorga/DpwZa/7/) shows the typical AngularJS two-way binding example, an input associated with a model through the ng-model directive.

```
<input ng-model="object.name" />
<div >Hello {{object.name}}</div>
```

But when I add a jasmine test, the two-way binding stops working, as you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JulianMayorga/DpwZa/5/). I used the [jasmine-all script](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-all) to embed the specs in the fiddle.

**Why does the two-way binding stop working (changing the input value should update the output div)? And how can I solve this problem?**

Thanks so much!

Comment: for me it works (Chrome)

Comment: It works for you Maxim? That's weird, I am also using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77 on Ubuntu, but it's not working for me. I also tried on firefox nightly and it does not work either.

Comment: Tested it both on windows & linux on chrome & firefox, not working!